# Spring Reactor: Is this Flux can get out of memory?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Consider the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        UnicastProcessor<Integer> processor = UnicastProcessor.create();
        Flux<Integer> source = Flux
                .just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
                .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(1))
                .repeat();

        source.subscribe(processor);

        processor.subscribe(i -> {
            System.out.println("i = " + i);
            System.out.println("processor.size() = " + processor.size());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        });

        Thread.currentThread().join();

    }
```

You can see that the delay of the `source` is much smaller than the delay of the subscriber (which sleeps for 1 second).

Questions:

1. Is this code might get out of memory?
2. I always see `processor.size() = 0`. Why? I expected the queue to be filled (it's unbounded)
3. If I remove `delayElements` command, I see nothing. Why?

Thanks!

Comment: placing `Thread.sleep` between `source.subscribe(processor);`  and `processor.subscribe(i -> ` makes whole chain behave as expected (queue is filling). However, I have no idea why - probably something with concurrent initilization. Rearranging order of streams does not change anything - feels a bit like a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Taking a look at the docs for `create()` on `UnicastProcessor`, it says:](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/UnicastProcessor.html#create--)

> Create a new UnicastProcessor that will buffer on an internal queue **in an unbounded fashion.**

(Emphasis mine.)

Specifically, this means that it if its subscriber hasn't yet requested data, it will attempt to buffer any data that's available. It doesn't know that the `Flux` you have there is infinite, so it sits there buffering as much of that data as it can.

> If I remove delayElements command, I see nothing. Why?

With the `delayElements()` call in there, that gives the millisecond needed for your subscriber to subscribe *before* that `Flux` starts emitting data - so at that point it doesn't try to buffer any of it, just sends it straight through to the Flux. Without it, the `Flux` emits values before the subscriber has subscribed, and so you get the infinite buffering sequence as above.

On the same vein, if you comment out the `repeat()` call on the Flux then it will also work fine, because the processor will then just buffer those 5 values until the subscribe call is made.

> Is this code might get out of memory?

In the case where the infinite buffering occurs, then yes - eventually there won't be enough memory for the processor to hold any more data.

> I always see processor.size() = 0. Why?

Because the *processor* isn't holding any values by the time it's published it to your subscriber - it doesn't need to buffer them at that point. If you called `size()` on the processor while it was attempting to buffer those values infinitely, then you'd see it constantly rise.